Trying to identify a movie about a killer that ends with him trapped in a well
So I've been trying to track this film down for years.  I think it was early eighties, somewhere around there.  It could very well have been R.
Here's the plot as best I can remember.
This guy is living in a two story house.  The cops show up for some reason, maybe they are after him, and he is shot.  Maybe his name is Tommy or Michael.  He is white as I think everyone in the film is.  He goes to the hospital and the doctor does some stuff and pronounces him dead.  Some people leave.  When they leave, the doctor cranks back up with his crew, does something,  and the guy comes back to life.  
However, he is basically a homicidal maniac (and I don't think he talks in the film).  At one point, the doctor puts his hand on the guy's neck and says something like you are my greatest creation and smiles.  The guy put his hand on the doctor's neck, smiles, and then breaks the doctor's neck.     
At the end, somehow the guy falls into a well and can't get out.  The implication is that he is stuck there for good.  Something by Pink Floyd plays at the end and I think it is part of "Another Brick in the Wall."
Does any of these crazy, scattered fragments ring a bell?
Thanks for your help.

I think the movie you are talking about is Silent Rage.  It stars Chuck Norris. I couldn't find the scene that you described with the doctors getting his neck snapped, but I was able to find a part showing where the murderer gets knocked into a well by Chuck:



The description from IMDB also seems to match:

Dan Stevens is the sheriff of a small Texas town who checks out a disturbance which turns to murder. The killer is still in the house and he tries to kill Dan, but Dan stops him and arrests him. The killer attempts to flee, but is shot and killed and is taken to a medical institute. Three doctors, led by Dr. Philip Spires, operate on the killer and using a formula the doctors made, they bring him back to life. If that's not bad enough, the formula also made the killer indestructible. Dr. Tom Halman tries to stop the killer, but he and his wife are killed. After the two remaining doctors are killed, the killer goes after Dr. Halman's sister Alison, and it's up to Sheriff Dan Stevens to stop him.

